# How is target area for SRC_IN xfermode drawing operation determined?

Tags: android, graphics, 2d

I'm writing an Android app that involves some 2D drawing operations. I am trying to use saveLayer and xfermode SRC_IN to draw the intersection of 2 images. It seems to work OK if I don't rotate anything, but if I rotate one of the images, it seems to treat the pixels outside the rotated rectangle bounding the image as opaque (part of the intersection), or more likely, as not part of the drawing operation (unaffected by the transparent pixels laid on top of it).

Below is a picture of what I'm talking about. The "5" and "3" images near the bottom are being "intersected" by drawing the "3" image (rotated) with xfermode SRC_IN on the "5". I have shown all three images on a gradient background to help visualize transparency.

After some thought, I suspect that the area outside the clipping rectangle of the "3" is not being treated as opaque, but rather simply not being treated as part of the drawing operation. What's interesting is that if I mark the layer as a software layer instead of a hardware layer the while number "5" shows up in the background instead of just the parts outside 3's clipping rectangle. I don't understand this.

How is the area affected by an SRC_IN drawing operation determined? (Normally it doesn't matter, but one unique feature of SRC_IN is that it has to turn opaque pixels transparent based on what is transparent in the image being drawn, so the overall size of that is drawn is important even though it normally wouldn't be.) How can I make the pixels outside the drawn area of the 3 be treated as not part of the intersection? Do I need to enlarge the clipping rectangle that is active when drawing the 3?

[image: Drawing intersection of 5 & 3]